# What happens to currently transfered file between two separate drives when power goes out?

Tags: hard-drive, file-transfer

All is in the title but here is the full explanation: I just got a new hard drive and I was trying to transfer Terabytes of data but because the house can't handle too many high wattage devices the power went out during transfer (and I don't have UPS unfortunately). I have too many files to check which one failed to transfer as I am re-doing the remaining of the transfer (I know in which overall directory the file that was transferring comes from when the power went out).

Source drive has GPT/NTFS and the destination drive has GPT/exFAT.

I wanted to know if the file could or is corrupted when power goes out during file transfer when transferring during two distinct Hard drives (mechanical drives).

Note that I'm using Windows 10 (Version 20H2. Build 19042.1586) in case the OS is a factor (I use default Windows copy method). The Drives are the same models (WD Ultrastar DC HC550 - SATA). one is connected through USB 3 the other directly to motherboard.

I also would like to know if it's still available in the source drive or, in case it's corrupted, if it's lost in both drives.

Comment: More important than the drives is the used file-system on the target drive.

Comment: @Robert the Partition Table is GPT and the file system is exFAT in the destination drive and NTFS in the source drive

Comment: Files certainly *could* be corrupted, and you would need to check. Though it  might take days to wipe the drive completely and to *start over* and transfer again, it is far more reassuring to do so. You might be better off using imaging software to transfer by direct disk I/O, which I find perhaps a hundred times faster than doing so file-by-file. If using Windows, use *Robocopy*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik unfortunately I was moving files not copying them.

Comment: Then if you don't have a backup image, why ask? You should consider, instead, the question of *how to evaluate files for corruption*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I do have backup for some of them. That's why I ask (I have backup online for the directory that was transferring when the power went out for instance). I just want to know if I'm gonna need to download everything or find backup from old drives an so on. You are right it's more about how to evaluate files for corruption.

Comment: To be clear (I think you already know this), there is no MOVE, only copy then delete on success.  The bytes remain on the source until a successful transfer is assured.  You need to identify which file lives in BOTH trees.  That should be the one with corruption (if any).

Comment: This question is very simple: The destination drive would be the one to have corrupted data. Cut off a file copy in mid-copy means the destination has a partial (aka: corrupted) file. It sounds like you are just dragging and dropping stuff from one drive to another which is not a great way to do this. A better tactic would be for you to use some kind if incremental data copying tool. That way if power drops the next time, the copy will continue from where it stopped and not from square one again.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the following (your specific situation in brackets):

1. the source file system (NTFS)
2. the target file system (exFAT)
3. operating system used (Windows 10)
4. possible installed file handlers (Teracopy p.e.)

Depending on Windows10 updating the "date acessed" attribute of your source files, there is even write activity on your source, but failing to update this information is not detrimental.

As for the target your copy operation requires Windows 10 to write files and folders.

In your case this involves writing

1. directory entries
2. writing data to unused clusters
3. updating the FAT

The update of the FAT (=file allocation table) is the most risky operation because the sectors of the FAT that need to be updated might contain information about other already existing files.

I would do the following:

1. run a **chkdsk M: /f /x** (replace "M" by your drive label, be aware that the parameter /x will render drive M temporarily unavailable and will break all open file operations of your programs that are running and are currently operating on M:)
2. Delete the remains of your copy operation
3. Copy your stuff again.

Verifying the already copied files is as time-consuming as copying again.

Retry. If there is a risk of power failures try to cut your copy job into parts. When the power breaks down, you should just delete the copied files of your last part job on the target.